# If nothing is selected in Jlist

Tags: java, jlist

I´m writing a program where different symbols are drawn on an image based on what the user selects in a JList. This works fine, but my problem is that I want to place a symbol on the image if nothing is selected in the JList as well. Is there some way to check if the selection is empty? This is my code right now, and it throws me a NullPointerException if I don´t select anything from the JList.

```
if(categoriesList.getSelectedValue().equals("Bus")) {
            BusSymbol bs = new BusSymbol(x, y);
            mp.add(bs);
        } 
        else if 
(categoriesList.getSelectedValue().equals("Underground")) {
            UndergroundSymbol us = new UndergroundSymbol(x,y);
            mp.add(us);
        }
        else if (categoriesList.getSelectedValue().equals("Train")) {
            TrainSymbol ts = new TrainSymbol(x,y);
            mp.add(ts);
        }
        else if (categoriesList.getSelectedValue().equals(null)) {

            NoCategorySymbol ncs = new NoCategorySymbol(x,y);
            mp.add(ncs);
        }

        mp.validate();
        mp.repaint();
```

Comment: That's because `null` has no `.equals` method. If something might be null, you want to check it with `== null` (or ideally with another method ; isn't there a `hasSelectedValue()` method on that API ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`JList.isSelectionEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#isSelectionEmpty()) as a condition instead of testing against the value that might be `null`.

You should either make this test first, and/or change all the other tests which have this unfortunate syntax :

```
mightBeNull.equals(neverNull)
```

As a general rule it is generally better to avoid this syntax and use `neverNull.equals(mightBeNull)` instead, as it avoids attempting to invoke the inexistant `null.equals()` method.

I propose the following code :

```
if (categoriesList.isSelectionEmpty()) {
    mp.add(new NoCategorySymbol(x,y));
} else {
    // here we know categoriesList.getSelectedValue() isn't null
    String selectedValue = categoriesList.getSelectedValue());
    if ("Underground".equals(selectedValue)) {
       mp.add(new UndergroundSymbol(x,y));
    } else if ("Train".equals(selectedValue)) {
       mp.add(new TrainSymbol(x, y));
    }
}
mp.validate();
mp.repaint();
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Works perfect! Thanks!

Comment: @Andpej You're welcome. Please flag the answer as accepted since it did solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't check for a null value using `.equals` you need to use `==`.

```
categoriesList.getSelectedValue() == null
```

This is because `.equals` calls a method on the object. If the object is null you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isElementSelected(){ return categoriesList.getSelectedValue() == null;}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.